# Making popup GtkMenu transparent and borderless in python Gtk3

Tags: python, user-interface, cairo, gtk3

I'm having trouble making a popup menu borderless and transparent using Python and Gtk3.  Using the same code I can make my main window and a message dialog styled appropriately, so what's wrong with me code? Adding `border-style: none` *(or for each side as below)* in the CSS definition only removes the bottom border. Here's a screen shot of what I've got. You can see the main window formatted correctly behind. Cairo is correctly drawing the background of the popup *(note the rounded corners inside the white rectangle, but it isn't transparent)*.

[image: screenshot]

**EDIT** I was able to get the menu transparent by getting the parent of the `Gtk.Menu` and setting/drawing on it.  But I haven't been able to get rid of the top, left and right borders. Just the bottom.

Here's the relevant code:

```
def __init__(self):
   ....#other code...

   css.load_from_data("""
        .title { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); color: rgba(%s,1);}
        .iconview { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); color: rgba(%s,1); font-size:%i}
        .background2 { background-color: rgba(%s,0.7);  color: rgba(%s, 1);border-top-style:none; border-left-style:none; border-right-style:none; border-bottom-style:none;}
    """ % (str(sel f.FONT_rgb).strip('[]'),str(self.FONT_rgb).strip('[]'),FONTSIZE,str(self.BG_rgb).strip('[]'),str(self.FONT_rgb).strip('[]')))
    Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), css,
        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

    parent=self.popup.get_parent()
    screen=parent.get_screen()

    parent.set_visual(screen.get_rgba_visual())
    parent.set_app_paintable(True)
    parent.get_style_context().add_class('background2')

    for child in self.popup.get_children():
        child.get_style_context().add_class('iconview')
        child.set_app_paintable(True)
    self.popup.get_style_context().add_class('iconview')
    self.popup.set_app_paintable(True)

    parent.connect("draw", self.draw_window_cb)

def on_mouse_click(self,widget, event):
    # Check if right mouse button was preseed
    if event.type == Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_RELEASE and self.dragging==False:

        if event.button == 3 and path != None:
            self.popup.popup(None, None, None, None, event.button, event.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
border-radius: 15       
border-width: 0
```

Comment: No good.  I tried that.  The only work around I can do is to make the radius as close to the cairo-drawn radius as possible.  However, you can still see that the top, left and right borders are a bit thicker than the bottom border (which is the only one that the 0px width affects)